# PHP access value of XML File

Tags: php, xml, youtube

How can I access the views of the newest Entry in this XML file?

https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCeNdjxcrWI5B1-j8mG4Nm7g

That is my attempted, but it's not working:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(sprintf('https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=%s', $channel_id));
            foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {
                if (!empty($entry->children('yt', true)->videoId[0])){
                  $views = $entry->children('group')->children('community')->statistics['views'];
                  echo $views;}}
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: Should be changed now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCeNdjxcrWI5B1-j8mG4Nm7g';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);
print_r($xml->entry->children('media', true)->group->community->statistics->attributes()->views);
```

Hope this helps ;)